# Taxonomy, views and menu

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, routes

I have a content type "basic".

That content type is using 3 taxonomy vocabularies.

- Vocabulary 1 - 5 terms
- Vocabulary 2 - 3 terms (term1, term2, term3)
- Vocabulary 3 - 6 terms

I have a view that displays all the content from this content type. There are three exposed filters for the three vocabularies, they are displayed as a exposed filter block top of the content and they are working great.

From a left side I have menu links that show the three terms of Vocabulary 2 and it looks like this:

- Term1
- Term2
- Term3

Now the problem is if I select Term2 menu link that shows the content related to that taxonomy term and use some of the exposed filter, there are no results displayed.

I mean I'm selecting a menu link Term2 from left and than I check some term, lets say from the third exposed filter and the result is nothing, even if there's a content that belongs to that term.

Is it possible that menu to not interfere the filter results?

Comment: If you click on **Term2** then it will redirect to a new page like http://yoursite.com/taxonomy/term/13, then how your exposed filter will work on that page? Are you using any ajax functionality? If you can please share a screen-shot of your page.

Comment: "If you click on Term2 then it will redirect to a new page like yoursite.com/taxonomy/term/13, then how your exposed filter will work on that page?" Yes, its not working. Is it possible to fix that? I'm not using Ajax.

Comment: Exposed filter you can use only with views. **yoursite.com/taxonomy/term/13** is not a view page. You can expose the filter as a block. And assign the block at the top of content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exposed filter you can use only with views. **yoursite.com/taxonomy/term/13** is not a view page. You can expose the filter as a block. And assign the block at the top of content.